# vb.net project template how can I leave the root namesapce empty

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, templates

I have been tinkering with the VS 2010 template. So far I am able to create a vb.net class library project from my template.

However, one small thing is bugging me.

In my project template the default assembly name is the same as the default file name. I have left the root namespace empty.

But when I create a new project from the template, VS 2010 automatically fills the root namespace with the same name as my assembly name.

My template project (vbproj) for the assembly name and root namespace looks like this:

```
<AssemblyName>$safeprojectname$</AssemblyName>
<!-- RootNameSpace should always be empty. -->
<RootNamespace></RootNamespace>
```

But as said, when I leave this empty it is always overwritten with the assembly name.
Even if I create a custom parameter with an empty string as value to replace the root namespace, it is still overridden.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you use VS 2012 now?  It looks like in 2012 you can define a namespace as directly below "Global" without having a blank root namespace: [link]http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2011/09/27/announcement-namespace-global.aspx.  Obviously this isn't what you were asking for but it might be a work around.

Comment: I use VS 2012, and you are correct Abraham, you can define namespaces below 'Global'.

Comment: @Wietze Veld: You can never have your Namespace as empty. When do you plan to change/update the Namespace name. Do you have an Wizard Extension to pop up something, to get the Namespace from user?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry I never got back to you (it was a while back :)).

@WIH, we used to do this manually, however, my question was how to do this programmatically.
We manually clear the root namespace and set the namespace in the class files themselves, this allows for multiple namespaces in one assembly.

When we introduced the templates, I wanted to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In the **Solution Explorer** -> right click on the solution -> Properties -> clear the ***Root namespace*** field -> press **Enter** to save.